# Pokémon Go: Thrown back to gym menu as soon as countdown ends

Tags: pokemon-go

First of all, sorry if it has been asked already. I couldn't find anything similar, though.

I tried to attack a hostile gym and it worked fine until then. I also caught some Pokémon on my way there and collected a few Pokéstops. So my guess is, that the connection was fine. 
Also the GPS positioning was good and I didn't get pushed out of the gym's range.
(The gym itself was at a main station, so it's a pretty busy place.)

The issue itself:
I could select the gym, tap on fight and select my combat Pokémon and start the fight with no issues. But as soon as the countdown for the first fight ended I got thrown back to the main menu of that gym and I had to tap on the fight button again.
I haven't seen this before and it was only this one gym. There was another gym in the area, which I could use as intended (this was a friendly one, though).

Do I have to report that gym or was it just a temporary problem? If so, what kind of problem was it?

**Update:**
I have collected several details about this using the classic method *try and error*. So far I got it reproduced even **without any connection issues**.

Narrowed down it can be caused by:

- GPS Problem (not server related)
- interrupted previous fight (app crash, etc)
- server issues

Comment: The game is only recently released, and even as the servers calm down and are upgraded, they're releasing the game in more regions. Expect some instability due to connection issues and server issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I guess this should be posted as a new answer instead of keeping the question updated by edits.*

I have collected several details about this using the classic method *try and error*. So far I got it reproduced even **without any connection issues**, but it can also be caused by them.

Narrowed down it can be caused by:

- GPS Problems 
  (Not server related and not the character walking away. That's a different problem. I'm talking about connectivity in this case.)
- Interrupted previous fight 
  (app crash, etc.)
- Server issues
- Soft Ban(?) - *requires another source*

There may be other things causing this error, but these are the ones I could figure out by testing a lot of gyms.

Comment: Just ran into this.  Definitely wasn't GPS or Ban related, as I was standing right next to the gym.  Must have been something on a server.

Answer (score 3):

Were you at a location where GPS accuracy may have been "suboptimal"?
What I experienced often in those cases, is that your location bounces around the area when your GPS updates and decides that you are now in a different location. If this temporary new "wrong" location is too far away from the gym, it may cancel ongoing fights.

In this case, you may sometimes still see the "Gym too far away" message in the gym main menu for a short moment.

Comment: I know of that bouncing error, but the player position was right on top of that gym at all times. The out of range error never appeared.

Comment: Then it is hard to say. The gym itself will most likely not be at fault / special, the more likely thing is temporary server issues, spontaneous network issues, a rare error in the app... My bet is on the servers.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a connection issue. Keep trying, or wait a little bit for the servers to calm down and try later.

Comment: I can by now confirm, that this is *not* a connection issue. I'm gonna need another gym to prove it, then I'll post the result.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen when you fight a pokemon which is just kicked from the gym by another player, You will be returned to the menu so you can fight against another pokemon.

The other could be that the gym was just emptied and there are no pokemon left to fight.

Another reason could be that your gps is wonky and displaces you and sets you outside of the gym area, this could mean you get kicked out and than you can challenge it again because the gps corrects itself

Comment: No, it was confirmed by other players, that kicking out a Pokémon doesn't interrupt ongoing fights. Also this is not about getting kicked out due to distance. I've already explained this.